# How to match a string with tuples

Tags: c#, string, tuples

I have a class that contains a tuple

```
public List<Tuple<int, char>> TVRPositions { get; set; }
```

I have added to this tuple list by turning a string into a char array the int represents the position of the char while the char represents the actual value.

I have to now compare those values with a string that I have turned into a char array called TVRBitArray. I have gone ahead by using a forloop and a foreach. What I realized is that this takes a lot of time and I have to unfortunately loop through quite a bit.

Here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < TVRBitArray.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (var tuple in CardRule.TVRPositions)
    {
        if (tuple.Item1 == i && tuple.Item2 == TVRBitArray[i])
        {
            if (listenerSettings.DebugOn)
            {
                logToFile.WriteLog("TVRMATCH = TRUE");
            }
            TVRMatch = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (listenerSettings.DebugOn)
            {
                logToFile.WriteLog("TVRMATCH = False");
            }
            TVRMatch = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a much more efficient way of matching my variables inside my tuple list to the second string to see if its a perfect match?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't just comparing the 2 strings `if(string1 == string2)` ? all this extra plumbing seems like you have overbaked this to the extreme

Comment: I cant compare the strings because the data in TVR bitarray will have a bunch of X's in the string. For example XXX0XXX1XX0. The data that I get from my array that goes into my tuple list has only 0's and 1's so it would like so 00000001000. Thats why I can't do a straight string compare unfornately

Comment: Can you not remove the X's ?

Comment: Is it intended to turn TVRMatch on and off on every iteration?

Comment: `if(string1.Replace("X","") == string2)` ?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ah no i made a mistake there its supposed to turn on if all positions within the tuple list match or turn off if they dont.

Comment: @Adil15 two questions - tuples in TVRPositions sorted by `Item1`? and does length of TVRPositions match the length of TVRBitArray?

Comment: @00110001 Wouldn't I still have a problem matching because the other string has many more zero's. I guess I am having a hard time explaining I just want to match the positions and values of the 0's and 1's from the string with X's to the one with just 0's and 1's

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes both are the same length I did not sort them though I just added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All items in TVRPositions should match corresponding bits in TVRBitArray or that bit should be set to X:

```
TVRMatch = CardRule.TVRPositions
    .All(p => TVRBitArray[p.Item1] == 'X' || TVRBitArray[p.Item1] == p.Item2);
```

Check [Enumerable.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0)

---

Also you can give nice names to the tuple items if you'll use [C# 7 Tuple Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

```
public List<(int Index, char Value)> TVRPositions { get; set; }
```

Then query will be more readable:

```
TVRMatch = CardRule.TVRPositions
    .All(bit => TVRBitArray[bit.Index] == 'X' || TVRBitArray[bit.Index] == bit.Value);
```

---

And you also can go directly with strings avoiding tuples and array of bits by zipping two strings:

```
var mask = "XXX0XXX1XX0";
var value = "00000001000";
TVRMatch = mask.Zip(value, (m, v) => m == 'X' || m == v).All(x => x);
```

Comment: I am getting operator || cannot be applied to operands of type bool and char am i missing something?

Comment: `==` in items comparison

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the problem. However, I now assume the `X`'s are a mask and the strings are the same length.

Maybe you want something like this

```
var result = mask 
   .Select((c, i) =>(c, i))
   .All(x => x.c =='X' || input[x.i] == x.c);
```

or

```
var result = mask 
   .Select((c, i) => c =='X' || input[i] == c)
   .All(x => x);
```

or

```
public static bool Check(string mask, string input) 
    => !mask.Where((t, i) => t != 'X' && t != input[i]).Any();
```

Usage

```
var mask = "XXX0XXX1XX0";
var input = "00000001000";
  
var result = Check(mask,input );

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
True;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sort and compare using Linq..

```cs
var pair = from item in CardRule.TVRPositions
           orderby item.Item1
           select item.Item2;

var ptnArray = pair.ToArray();

if (ptnArray.SequenceEqual(TVRBitArray))
   // true
else
   // false
```